# Keep a thread running even when hitting a breakpoint

Tags: c#, multithreading

I wish to develop a debugging service that needs to run constantly in the background, even when I hit a breakpoint -- especially during those moments. Is there any way I could do that, other than having to manually unfreeze the specific thread in the thread window ? I'd like it to be something I don't have to take care of manually. I thought about creating a thread that run inside another appDomain, but I bet that thread will also end up frozen when I hit a breakpoint. I have not tested it though.

Comment: I you have a thread that hits a breakpoint it stops. If you have two threads and one hits the breakpoint that one stops but the other one keeps going. Otherwise, what's the point of the breakpoint?

Comment: the second one does not keep going, that's what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: The thread that I want running at all times is a special thread that serves as an evaluator that helps with the debugging while the execution of the actual program is stopped.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea why one needs a thread for debugging but ok... You should read about the basics of multi threading. @Enigmativity is right, if your behaviour is different you are doing something wrong. Maybe you are awaiting the second thread?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood correctly the statement above. But what I'm saying is that if I'm hitting a breakpoint at line "a" and just wait, the second thread (b) wont progress. Both threads are frozen. 

            Task.Run(() =>{ 
                Debug.WriteLine("### a ");
               

            });

            Task.Run(() => {
                Debug.WriteLine("### d ");
               
            });

Comment: Regarding reading basics about multithreading, I don't think this would help because what I'm trying to do is sort of messing with the way the debugger works. Standard manipulations, especially the basics won't help I think

Comment: "I have absolutely no idea why one needs a thread for debugging but ok..."

In a nutshell, I want this thread to answer requests from an outside application that will interrogate the debugger about the state of  the objects that I'm debugging.  :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found a solution. I will make a visual studio extension. I did some tests and it's possible to have a thread running in the background all the time within an extension

Here's a simple proof of concept that keeps emiting the result of an evaluation, even when the debugger hits a breakpoint:

```
private Command1(AsyncPackage package, OleMenuCommandService commandService)
{
    Task.Run(() => {
        DTE dte = (DTE)ServiceProvider.GetServiceAsync(typeof(DTE)).Result;     
        while (true)
        {
            Expression ex2 = dte.Debugger.GetExpression("WinFormsApp1.Test.RunStatic(str);");
            Debug.WriteLine("### " + ex2.Value);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

The logic starts when Command1 is initialized, which won't be appropriate for the real thing, but good enough for the POC.

Comment: Show us your tests. Show us a solution. Don't just say you've found one.

Comment: I just posted an update.